# Best practice to store online time log in MySQL

Tags: mysql

TL;DR further down.

I'm writing a PHP script that uses cURL to get player info from a game site (Tibia, if anyone cares) and store it in a database.

The player info I'm storing is player name, server, level, vocation, login times and logout times. This info will be used to make highscore lists on player level gains, online time etc.

I've already made two prototypes of this script. The first one checks the online list of a server and creates a new row for each online player every loop of the script. This creates a lot of rows, and the database size gets out of hand real quick, but the data is really easy to run mysql queries on.

The other version of the script checks the online list of a server, but only inserts new rows if the player is not already in the database or has leveled up since last script loop. The new rows are created with an empty "sessionEnd" timestamp column. When a loop of the script notices a player has logged out, the "sessionEnd" column will be filled with the appropriate timestamp.

The problem is that to do this, I have to compare all unended session rows from the DB to the current online player list (from the website), and that makes the script run slow and make my CPU cry. Another problem with this is that running queries tied to online time gets complicated compared to the other version where I can do a simple COUNT() on X player to get the online time. However, this keeps the database size really small.

TL;DR
What's the best way to store a users online time?

```
id   username   loginTime   logoutTime     level
1    myuser      10:38         11:54       48
2    myuser      10:54         11:31       49
```

Or like...

```
id   username   timestamp   level
1    myuser      10:38       48
2    myuser      10:39       48
3    myuser      10:40       48
4    myuser      10:41       49
```

Comment: I'd say the former, but I'd say it also comes down to personal preference.

Comment: It more depends on the sorts of queries you are going to run against the data. Try a few out for these two forms and see which ones end up the simplest.

Comment: Thank you both. I think I'm going with the terabyte version because of the simplicity. It's way easier for my CPU, and storage is cheap

Answer (score 0):

According to replies it seems both practices are viable.

I think I'm gonna use the storage heavy, cpu friendly route. It's way easier to run queries against the data that way and my puny laptop can multitask while running the script. Hope this helps someone